# How to load CRL for SSL verification from PEM string in python SSL library?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I am receiving PEM CRL files from a webservice.
I would like to create an SSL context which would use this CRL information for validation.
However if I pass this data as a string in this way : load_verify_locations(ca_data = crl_data), I get an exception.

Is there a way to directly load CRL into an SSL context, or do I need to write it out as files first?

Some example code: (please ignore that the CRL is loaded from file)

```
import ssl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # !! crl_data comes from a webservice !!
    with open("path to my CRL file", "r") as f:
       crl_data = f.read()

    ctx = ssl.SSLContext()
    ctx.load_verify_locations(cadata=crl_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, loading CRL data through the cadata parameter is not supported, according to this bug report on the official python issue tracker:
https://bugs.python.org/issue22365